# Locking car with key fob

Tags: locks, lexus, smartkey, unlock

I have a Lexus is250. I lock my car once and after few seconds after it unlocks. Any reason why it’s doing this?

Comment: Does it always do this or just sometimes? You might have a defective fob or are inadvertently unlocking it.

Comment: Do you get any warnings of opened doors, trunk and etc. while you are driving? How long has been since you've changed battery in your fob?

Comment: Do you have another fob?  Can you be certain it's not in the car (fallen under a seat or something)?

Answer (score 7):

This is usually because a door is not properly shut, at least that is what happens with my car, done as a warning to you so you don't leave thinking it is locked.

If the doors, hood and trunk are all properly shut then it may be a sensor.

It may also help to have a code reader as, even though there may not be a code, it can tell you the state of all doors etc.

Comment: I would emphasise, it could be any portion which the vehicle notices as "open". It may even tell you on the dash one of the portals is open. Everything may appear as closed (visually), but if one of them isn't closed properly, it'll not keep the vehicle locked (reopen the locks). I've also seen where there's an audible tone when locking to note the car alarm has been set (on second button press on key fob), the tone won't sound under the same conditions, though the locks will remain locked (no auto-unlocking).